# What is the meaning of pattern="^POST$" in url rewrite pattern and what matches this pattern

Tags: asp.net, redirect, iis

Examine this rule...

```
    <rule name="RedirectUserFriendlyURL1" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^viewcategory\.aspx$" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{REQUEST_METHOD}" pattern="^POST$" negate="true" />
        <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="^cat=([^=&amp;]+)$" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="viewcategory/{C:1}" appendQueryString="false" />
    </rule>
```

What is POST in pattern, and what matches this pattern?

Comment: It is a Regex. It matches all the POST requests. `^` means start of the line and `$` means end.